# Zoom in mobile websites and webview

Tags: android, android-layout, web, zooming, android-webview

Is it possible to add zoom to mobile targeted website?

I use webview and I need that mobile website's text is bigger and I think this can be solution  if I'm able to zoom in. But `Web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`is not working. It doesn't allow me to zoom.

Edit:
**Here is what I have now:**

```
    Web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    Web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    Web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    Web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    Web.loadUrl(URL);
    Web.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
    Web.getSettings().setRenderPriority( RenderPriority.HIGH );
    Web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    Web.setWebViewClient(new ErrorWebViewClient());
```

Edit2:
This is how I tried Mocialov Boris's answer:

```
View zoom;  
FrameLayout mContentView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.web);

Web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
Web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
Web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
Web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
Web.loadUrl(URL);
Web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
Web.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
Web.getSettings().setRenderPriority( RenderPriority.HIGH );
Web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
Web.setWebViewClient(new ErrorWebViewClient());

mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
zoom = Web.getZoomControls();
mContentView.addView(zoom);
zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution it is important to have implemented handler, because it will do changes to your UI from some thread. You said that app was crashing after you added this `mContentView.addView(zoom);` line, I assume that that was the problem

```
View zoom;  
FrameLayout mContentView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);

    Web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    Web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    Web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    Web.loadUrl(URL);
    Web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    Web.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
    Web.getSettings().setRenderPriority( RenderPriority.HIGH );
    Web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    Web.setWebViewClient(new ErrorWebViewClient());

    mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    zoom = Web.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            System.out.println("got msg");
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:
                mContentView.addView(zoom);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: have you tried touching the screen? because the initial visibility is set to 'gone' which means if you press, i might appear

Comment: Yeah I tried touch, pinch and double click it. Didn't work :(

Comment: maybe there is a problem when you have setBuiltInZoomControls(true); and getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); together. And also i use my setBuiltInZoomControls(true) in the on create and after loading url

Comment: i have tried it now and seems like there is a problem in my solution. You should do mContentView.addView(zoom); after you load the url (loadUrl("http://...")); then it works.. at least for me

Comment: Can you update your code? Because when I just add mContentView.addView(zoom); 
after 
Web.loadUrl(URL);
it just forceclose

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post. If it fails again, show your logcat then